# Update Choice column in Sharepoint using workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, metadata, choice-field, metadata-navigation

I have a Sharepoint library where I receive folders via email. I have a calculated column that determines the week ending date (as a string value) for the folder and I want to create a choice column that inherits these dates so it can be used for metadata navigation.

Question is: can I create a workflow that updates the choice column when a new folder is added with a new week ending date?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you can update choice field using workflow (may be using rest-api you can do it, but since I have not used rest-api so not sure on it).

One alternative is instead of choice column you can create lookup column and save the values in lookup list. So whenever new folder created, workflow will add value as a new row in lookup list and that value will be available using lookup column to select.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SharePoint do you have? Online or On-premises?

It is not possible to do it only with workflow.

If you have On-Premises version you can:

1. Build web service
2. Write c# code to update choice column. Example [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f30ebbf0-513e-4320-9d0a-3a641df9f58f/add-value-to-choice-column?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)
3. Build workflow and use action - "Call Web Service"

Or you can create event receiver and put C# code to update choice column.

It will work only for on-premises SharePoint.